# angular-ui router With two html pages

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router

My project has the file home, page1, page2.
My home page has a different header layout than the rest of my pages. So, it is a separate html file. page1 and page 2 is using ui routing to load in the content of the page, but the header and footer are the same.

My Question is: if I am on the home page and click btn 1. how do I get it to load in the content of page1? (It will load index.html, but no content of btn1.)

I'm not sure if passing an id to the index.js is a solution and I'm not sure how to even do that. Would it make more sense to just make the entire thing a SPA?

My home.html with the buttons:

```
<a type="text/html" href="home.html"  class="button home_btn">Home</a>
<a type="text/html" href="index.html" class="button my_btn1">Page1</a>
<a type="text/html" href="index.html" class="button my_btn2">Page2</a>
```

My idex.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="app">
      <header ng-include="'html/header.html'"></header>
        <div ui-view></div>
      <footer ng-include="'html/footer.html'"></footer>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="vendors/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js     </script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
```

my header.html:

```
<div id="headerLinks">
            <a type="text/html" href="home.html" class="button home_btn">Home</a>
            <a type="text/html" ui-sref="page1" class="button my_btn1">Page1</a>
            <a type="text/html" ui-sref="page2" class="button my_btn2">Page2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my index.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
    app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
          .state('Page1', {
            url: 'Page1',
            templateUrl: 'Page1.html',
            controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
          })
          .state('Page2', {
            url: 'Page2',
            templateUrl: 'Page2.html',
            controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
          })

  }])
```

Comment: I have this exact same question. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I"m kinda confused by what I was asking now that I look at it. I believe I was asking how to build a router with multiple pages. I got that to work. if this doesn't help, I'll see if I can find a resource or explain it better.

import angular-ui-router.

```
<script src="vendors/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is what my index.js file now looks like. it has multiply  views which allow for different header or content or footer or whatever.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ui.router',
  'ctrls'
]);

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $state) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); 
  $stateProvider
  .state('home',{
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'html/headerHome.html',
        controller: 'headCtrl'
      },
      'content': {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        //controller: 'ContentController' 
      }
    }
  })
  .state('page1', {
    url: '/page1',
    views: {
      'header': {
        templateUrl: 'html/header.html',
        controller: 'headCtrl'
      },
     'content': {
        templateUrl: 'page1.html',
        controller: 'page1Ctrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('page2', {
    url: '/page1',
    views:{
      'header':{
        templateUrl: 'html/header.html',
        controller: 'headCtrl'
      },
      'content':{
        templateUrl: 'page2.html',
        controller: 'page2Ctrl'
      }
    }
  })
```